# How many people could fit into a spaceship?

Tags: science-fiction, space, space-travel, near-future

I’m writing a story where the world is coming to an end but I want it to sound as realistic as possible.

The story takes place in 2024, not too far from now, and NASA sends out a crew in space to find a habitable planet that is safe for humans to live on. In the meantime, there are spacecrafts that are under construction back on earth with an unknown amount of people it can hold. That’s is why I am asking this question now.

How many people would you think could fit in a massive fictional space craft? My mind wants me to make up a number but the other side of my mind wants to make it realistic as possible. What would you think?

Comment: I once read about a globe shaped ship, with levels each few meters, and about as big as a fair sized moon. The number of people on that ship outdid the number of people the planet it stopped at. I do not remember numbers but it came to millions, maybe many millions.

Comment: 2024 is very close. A big question is how long you want them to survive for. Probably many hundreds could be sent and could survive for many months. maybe a hundred or so for a few years but that's about it after ten years they're all dead.

Comment: We already know that there are no inhabitable planets nearby to Earth so NASA does not need to send anyone out to look

Comment: 2024 near-term means no closed-loop life support. You travelers must carry all the food and water and fuel and CO2 scrubbers and extra air and spare parts and other expendables that they will need for their journey. If the journey is more than a couple days, that will vastly outmass and outvolume the travelers.

Comment: Your question is poorly phrases. Try reading it as "how many people can fit in a ship that is sent across the ocean?" without having any info on the particular ship.

Comment: 2024 ?  Totally unrealistic unless you can tell us what (fictional) technologies are available to to make such a craft with.  It's inconceivable with technologies available to send any crewed vehicle beyond Mars, let alone a different star.  Even Mars would be a huge and likely impossible task for a 2024 launch for even a one or two person ship.

Comment: With current technology, it would take thousands of years for even a small robotic probe to reach another star, an interstellar planet-hunting expedition in 2024 is completely impossible. The only planet searches we'll be doing in 2024 will be with telescopes. A big space telescope is well-suited to the task, but you wouldn't put crew on one. Even if we knew of such a planet, we'd be better off settling Mars or the asteroids than trying to send a generation ship on a multi-millennia trip to reach it.

Answer (score 3):

**Go with what you know.**

[image: cruise ship]

Cruise ships are the largest passenger vehicles that currently exist.  Here is [Symphony of the Seas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_of_the_Seas) - 361 meters long, capable of carrying 5518 passengers and 2200 crew.  Everything they need is aboard, plus extra space for recreation.

In your world, spacecraft are made of retrofitted cruise ships.  The ships have the infrastructure for large numbers of passengers already, and they are already built so there is time savings and your people are in a hurry.  They need spacecraft hull and propulsion built around them.  Large tanks of water will be added all around and used as reaction mass, oxygen stores and shielding from radiation.  In a way the ships are still on the water.

This would also give grist for the literary mill: the ships will have vestiges of their prior lives, some of which will be kept for the new role and some repurposed as needed.  For example the "Central Park" of the Symphony will be repurposed for food growing tanks and left open to the sun.

I assert the ships will all keep their old names.

Comment: I just want to note, that as cool as retrofitting ships/submarines/battleships as spacecraft is, it's also totally ridiculous--and not for the reasons you might think  (pressure difference)! None of those are built to take the acceleration of getting into orbit. None of those can endure the thermal variations of being in direct sunlight in vacuum. None of those can protect the crew from radiation. None of those have electronics which can withstand the charging effects of being a large metal surface in the solar wind. Not to mention that almost all pumps & plumbing require gravity to function.

Comment: Not to mention, they're absurdly heavy and stand no chance of being launched on anything we could possibly develop in the next 50 years.

Comment: @neph - you would not include the propeller when you sent them into space.  You would skin them of their hull and take out the engine.  Then put the innards into a space going vessel.

Comment: I didn't mention anything about the ship's propulsion system. All my points still stand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not realistic to build a large spaceship in that timeframe.  The only planet we have any serious consideration of getting to is Mars, and that would involve a handful of astronauts. We do not have the framework in place to get humans to Mars by 2024.

Realistically, getting to another habitable planet will take centuries and we will have to find it first.